# Vue.js "cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined" when accessing array of objects using Vue variable as index

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Having a small problem when accessing Vue data from within the `data()`, originally I was getting a few errors saying that variables were undefined but I realised pretty quickly that it was because of the order I defined them in, so I changed the order so that it wouldn't be a problem anymore but I'm still getting a `cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined` when trying to access an array of objects defined above whilst using a Vue variable as the index.

**App.vue**

```
export default {
data(){
  return {
    correct: 0,
    total: 0,
    currentText: 0,
    position: 0,
    userText: '',
    texts: [{
        text: 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog',
        textSize: '50px'
      },{
        text: 'sphinx of black quartz judge my vow',
        textSize: '50px'
      }
    ],
    textSize: this.texts[this.currentText].textSize
  }
}
```

Comment: The value of `this` is not what you think it is. You cannot refer to an "under construction" object from inside the object initializer. You'll have to set up the `textSize` property outside the initializer in a separate statement. Or it may be that `textSize` should really be method, so that it can dynamically return the size of the current text.

Comment: @Pointy would creating a method that accesses `this.texts[this.currentTexts].textSize` circumvent the error?

Comment: Yes. If `textSize()` were a *method*, then when called (if called properly, as a method of the returned object) then it would be able to use `this`.

Comment: `this` points to a different object. you can try putting it in a `computed` hook instead

Comment: @Pointy how would i go about calling the method as a method of the returned object because just defining `getTextSize(){ return this.texts[this.currentText].textSize }` as a vue method isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, use a computed:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        // Stuff
    }
  },
  computed: {
    textSize: function() {
      return this.texts[this.currentText].textSize
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can still access `textSize` in your template like you would access any `data` property, for example. A computed essentially caches the value, so each time you access it, the computed will only run if the value changes. A method, on the other hand, will be executed every time it's requested because a method doesn't know if a value has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Define textSize as a computed property.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      correct: 0,
      total: 0,
      currentText: 0,
      position: 0,
      userText: '',
      texts: [
        {
          text: 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog',
          textSize: '50px'
        },
        {
          text: 'sphinx of black quartz judge my vow',
          textSize: '50px'
        }
      ],
    },
    computed: {
      textSize() {
        return this.texts[this.currentText].textSize
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: This is probably the idiomatic "Vue" way of doing things.

Comment: But is has some advantages like computed caching. You can read about it in official docs [link](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

Comment: Yes, I meant that as a compliment to the solution, as opposed to mine; I don't know much about Vue.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is make `textSize` a getter method:

```
export default {
  data() {
    const object = {
      correct: 0,
      total: 0,
      currentText: 0,
      position: 0,
      userText: '',
      texts: [{
        text: 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog',
        textSize: '50px'
      }, {
        text: 'sphinx of black quartz judge my vow',
        textSize: '50px'
      }],
    };
    Object.defineProperty(object, "textSize", {
      get: function() {
        return object.texts[object.currentText].textSize;
      }
    });
    return object;
  }
}
```